# How can I dissect this JavaScript callback functions example?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm new to JavaScript and programming and I've read at least 8 or 9 different examples/tutorials explaining callback functions. From what I can tell, this is a concept that gives new programmers quite a bit of trouble. I understand why to use them, and how to use them, but I'm still not sure I understand *why* they work. I've written the following example:

```
function a(callback) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("First");
  callback();
 }, 2000);
}

function b(callback) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Second");
  callback();
 }, 1000);
}

function c() {
 console.log("Third");
}

function d() {
 a(function() {
  b(function() {
    c(); 
   });
 });
}
```

This code works as function a runs first, even though it takes the longest, and function b runs second, even though it takes longer than c. I understand that I've inserted a parameter called 'callback' into functions a and b, and that these functions will run whatever function whose name I insert in place of the 'callback' parameter whenever they are run, as per the 'callback();' line. For example, if I type `a(b);` into the console, the result is First, Second. If I type `b(c);` into the console, I get Second, Third.

The part that I'm not really understanding is what I've written in function d, where I'm having all 3 functions run. Function d executes function a, but it looks to me like it includes an anonymous function as a parameter, which runs function b, which also include an anonymous function as a parameter, which runs function c. What is it that's happening here? Why doesn't it work by typing `a(b(c));` into the console?

I guess I'm not really seeing the link between function d and the callback parameters that are in functions a and b. Specifically, when I do `a(b);` it's easy for me to see how it works. But when I do `a(function() {b();})`, which produces the same result, I'm not really understanding why it works.

Would someone explain how function d works, or why `a(function() {b();})` is the same as `a(b);` in this example?

Comment: because a calls b which calls c.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is it that's happening here? Why doesn't it work by typing a(b(c)); into the console?

writing a(b(c)); it's the same as:

a(
  b(c)
);

which means that you're executing a, but before that you're executing b passing c as a parameter, which means that:

b is executed first
b executes c
a receives as a parameter whatever b is returning and tries to execute it, but since b isn't returning anything, as soon as a tries to execute something that doesn't exist it gives the error "callback is not a function" because undefined isn't a function

> I guess I'm not really seeing the link between function d and the callback parameters that are in functions a and b. Specifically, when I do a(b); it's easy for me to see how it works. But when I do a(function() {b();}), which produces the same result, I'm not really understanding why it works.

is always useful to see things more divided:

```
a(
  function() {
    b();
  }
)
```

a is executed, and as a parameter it receives an anonymous function
a executes the function that received as a parameter (the anonymous one)
the anonymous function then (and only then) executes b

> Can someone dissect this for me and help me understand how function d works, or why a(function() {b();}) is the same as a(b); in this example?

it isn't the same (well, not quite), in a(function() {b();}) you pass an anonymous function to a, which in this case is barely a call to b, but that anonymous function could contain more instructions, like so:

```
a(
    function() {
        console.log("I'm no longer the same!");
        b();
    }
)
```

so, if you would want to make sure a calls back something more than b then you would (in this case) use an anonymous function, but if you only want to execute b through a you would use a(b);

now, consider this:

```
a(
    function(){}
)
```

it's the same, except that function doesn't do a thing

```
a(
    function(){
        console.log('anonymous');
    }
)
```

would print anonymous, but:

```
a(
    function(){
    console.log('anonymous');
  }()
)
```

would print anonymous and one second later a would throw an error (callback is not a function) because function is being executed (notice the () I added) and isn't returning anything, now let's move the function and give it a name (let's say, x):

```
function x(){
  console.log('anonymous');
}

a(
  x()
)
```

as you can see, a(x()) isn't the same as a(x), the difference is that when you write () in front of a function that function is executed and it's value is whatever it returns, but if you don't write that () it would be just a reference to the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
a(function() {
  b(function() {
    c(); 
   });
});
```

This means "execute the a function, passing in a new function who's text is:

```
function() {
  b(function() {
    c(); 
   });
}
```

... ". So it makes the function, and calls a. a sets up a timer, and 2 seconds later, it calls the function you created. While executing the function, it finds this instruction:

```
b(function() {
    c(); 
});
```

Which means "execute the b function, passing in a new function who's text is:

```
function() {
    c(); 
}
```

... ". So it does that next. b gets called, which sets up a timer, and when b goes off, it executes the function you passed into it. As part of executing that function, it calls c.

> Why doesn't it work by typing a(b(c)); into the console?

b(c) means "execute the b function, passing in the c function"
a(b(c)) means "execute the a function, passing in the return value of b(c)"

So when a(b(c)) executes, it immediately runs b(c), because it needs to know what it returns. b(c) sets up a timer, and then immediately returns undefined (this is implicit, since there's no return statement). This undefined then gets passed into a. a sets up a timer and returns undefined.

In approximately 1 second, the timer created by b goes off, and so it calls c (which is what was passed into it. Approximately 1 second after that (2 seconds from the start), the timer created by a goes off. Since undefined was passed into a, i expect you'll get an exception since undefined is not a function.